# Конфликт стилей в редакторе gutenberg

Tags: wordpress, acf, gutenberg

Я подключил и настроил блоки через ACF, но есть конфликт стилей.
Например в макете есть кнопки, они имеют класс .button , что в редакторе переписывается стилями вордпресса.

Может кто то пожалуйста подсказать как с этим справиться?

Comment: Все кастомные стили должны иметь префикс проекта. Например, проект (сайт) называется Super Food for Dogs. Префикс можно назначить sfd, и класс кнопки тогда .sfd-button. Тогда не будет конфликтов.

Comment: Это не всегда возможно, особенно если верстка делалась сторонними людьми и на основе фремворка.
Так же, в т.ч нужно переписать стили заголовков, у которых то по факту классов нету.

Comment: А не надо принимать вёрстку без префиксов. Вам говорят, как делать правильно, а вы упорствуете.

Comment: Простите, я не хочу что бы мои рассуждения звучали как грубость.
По мне это выглядит странным что такой момент не был предусмотрен заранее.
Например проблема не только в кнопках, заголовки, спаны, все переписывается библиотекой wp-core ui * которая грузиться в редакторе чанком, это значит, что всегда будет в очереди позже и переписывать нужные стили
UPD: имею ввиду простые элементы без классов.

Comment: Я в т.ч сам занимался рисчерчем.
Нормальный адаптив в самом гутенберге для кастомных блоков, ровно как и проблема конфликтных стилей должна уйти после переезда на айфреймы, но это пока только на запланированном обсуждении, которое будет не раньше 2021 года ))

Comment: Нет такой проблемы в принципе - перекрыть любые стили. Но это неправильно. Вам пояснили, как надо делать, а вы рассуждаете о высоких материях, о каком-то переезде Gutenberg на iframe (ссылку дайте, где это обсуждалось на https://make.wordpress.org/core/tag/gutenberg/).